# JSF MyFaces: Monitoring numberOfViewsInSession and numberOfLogicalViews

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I'm currently working on a web application with about 10 pages and a medium complexity.
We started our performance tests the other day and the following exception could be noticed in the logs:

```
2011-08-01 15:30:38,075 ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /pages/mypage.jsfNo saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /pages/mypage.jsf
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:88)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.DefaultSubjectValve.invoke(DefaultSubjectValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:406)
        at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:419)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1509)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've been reading the forums and most of them will mention the below properties that control the maximum number of views stored in one particular session:

com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession
com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews

Before trying to set values other than the default I would have liked to see how many views do we have in the sessions in the first place. I'm looking at something like:

User: x, views: y, logicalViews: z.

Does anyone know how can I get this kind of data please?

P.S. The app is running on a WASCE environment and uses myfaces-1.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

com.sun.faces.* is Mojarra not MyFaces.
You should try [org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Performance) instead.